# Javascript: running OnLoad code without access to <body> or <head>?

Tags: javascript, dom, hook, onload, head

I'm modding a web page that's generated by a third party project. The project essentially does something like this when your browser requests a page (pseudocode):

```
<?php
include: project's fixed library INCLUDE's
include: my freeform php code
?>

(project's fixed HTML <head>...</head> and <scripts/> sections)
(project's fixed HTML <body> tag and page header + frames)

(my freeform php/HTML code)

(project's fixed HTML footer, frame closures, and </body> tag)
```

The page contains form elements and HTML that's generated and filled in by php based on $_GET/$_POST. My HTML contains **"OnChange=ValidateItems();"** for most fields; when the user changes data on the page, error messages will appear inline if relevant.

What I want is to also trigger **"ValidateItems();"** after the page loads, when the initial user-provided values are set up in the HTML ready for the user. But I don't have access to usual  or  placements due to the above loading structure. I'm wondering how else to make it happen.

One option I was thinking was to add a tiny invisible frame/frameset/iframe or other object that does support onload and isn't reliant on the  or  tags, and 'bootstrap' myself from an onload= call of that, to then manually add onload to the body, or hook the usual onload event somehow, in order to call **ValidateItems()** once at the right time, then exit the snippet once it's set up or done.  I have no idea what the best way to do this - how I'd initially get any code to execute, what I'd then hook or modify etc so it happens appropriately (not too early or late); this is leagues past me technically. Help and example code would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add this somewhere inside your 'freeform html' code:

```
<script>
  window.onload = ValidateItems;
<script>
```

Comment: I tried this again (it didn't work before), and it does work - but only if it occurs after the items being validated. Put it in the form HTML, but before the items being validated, and it fails, put it towards the end of the <body> or after the items being validated, and it works. Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure that you've put `window.onload = ValidateItems` and not just `ValidateItems()`? With `window.onload = ValidateItems`, `ValidateItems` will get executed after whole page has been loaded. Just calling `ValidateItems()` will execute it immediately and, if you put it _before_ elements that `ValidateItems` needs access to, it wont't work simply because they have not been loaded yet.